# Angular 2 Laravel start

Tags: laravel-5, angular

I follow this tutorial

https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-and-angular-2-beta-setup/

and this

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/angular2-laravel-hello-world-app

But I get that error:

```
Error: @http://localhost/naturedev/public/js/app.js:40:1
@http://localhost/naturedev/public/js/app.js:1:1
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost/naturedev/public/js/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:332:20
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost/naturedev/public/js/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:227:25
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost/naturedev/public/js/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:576:53
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost/naturedev/public/js/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:365:24
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost/naturedev/public/js/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:263:29
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost/naturedev/public/js/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:482:26
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost/naturedev/public/js/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:434:22

Evaluating http://localhost/naturedev/public/js/app.js
Error loading http://localhost/naturedev/public/js/app.js
var newErr = new Error(newMsg, err.fileName, err.lineNumber);
```

This is how my gulp file look like:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var bower = require("gulp-bower");
var elixir = require("laravel-elixir");
var elixirTypscript = require('elixir-typescript');
elixir(function (mix) {
   mix.copy('node_modules/angular2', 'public/js/angular2');
   mix.copy('node_modules/rxjs', 'public/js/rxjs');
   mix.copy('node_modules/systemjs', 'public/js/systemjs');
   mix.copy('node_modules/es6-promise', 'public/js/es6-promise');
   mix.copy('node_modules/es6-shim', 'public/js/es6-shim');
   mix.copy('node_modules/zone.js/dist', 'public/js/zone.js/dist');
   mix.typescript(
    [
        'app.component.ts',
        'boot.ts'
    ],
    'public/js',
    {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    }
);
});
```

Full code is just published [here](https://github.com/stojankukrika/l5a2-test).

Gulp create [app.js](https://github.com/stojankukrika/l5a2-test/blob/master/public/js/app.js) file from [boot.ts](https://github.com/stojankukrika/l5a2-test/blob/master/resources/assets/typescript/boot.ts) and [app.component.ts](https://github.com/stojankukrika/l5a2-test/blob/master/resources/assets/typescript/app.component.ts).

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please add the relevant content to the question directly instead of just external links. Add code and error messages as text instead of screenshots to make it searchable for others that run into the same issue.

Comment: I do not know what is the error and how to fix that error. I didn't find it in google so I do not know what to do. Can you tell me what I need to do to fix this question?OK, I see now the rest of your comment. TNX.

Comment: I don't know how to fix the error, but I know how to improve your question (see my previous comment). Better questions are more likely to be answered.

Comment: You should add the relevant code as you were already told. The error mentions a `js/app.js` file, what does it contain? Make sure to put the files in order in your gulp file, etc.  Make sure you have the latest version of everything.

Comment: I just push it all into github and there you can find all code that you need to see. I hope that will help you to find out what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: @mrakdol Where within that repo is the TS that generates the in public/js? Make sure you've put the full error message in your question. Usually there's a Zone.js related error and another one in the console marked "ORIGINAL EXCEPTION" or something similar.

Comment: @eppsilon, please look at my update of answer.

Comment: Just a guess: in tsconfig.json (or in your gulpfile) add `"noImplicitUseStrict": true` to the compiler options. If that doesn't work, try breaking down your code into a simpler example. I'd recommend separating the PHP stuff from the JS stuff as a first step. Ideally your Angular app would be just a plain SPA that doesn't know anything about the backend it's talking to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to open file **node_modules\elixir-typescript\index.js**:

Comment out this line "`.pipe($.concat(paths.output.name))`" : So the generated files won't be combine in to one single files. The two js files will be generated to "public/js" as your configuration.

I checked your code, you already had this: "`///<reference path="../../../public/js/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>`" in **boot.ts** file. That's good.

Modify the file **index.blade.php** change `System.import('js/app')` to `System.import('js/boot')`

Modify the file **app.component.ts**, change `selector: 'my-app'` to s`elector: 'naturedev-app'`. That is how you configured in **index.blade.php**, so we need to make them with the same name.

And the last one, you need to change the **gulpfile.js** configuration, find this:

```
mix.copy('node_modules/angular2', 'public/js/angular2');
mix.copy('node_modules/rxjs', 'public/js/rxjs');
mix.copy('node_modules/systemjs', 'public/js/systemjs');
mix.copy('node_modules/es6-promise', 'public/js/es6-promise');
mix.copy('node_modules/es6-shim', 'public/js/es6-shim');
```

And change to

```
mix.copy('node_modules/angular2', 'public/angular2');
mix.copy('node_modules/rxjs', 'public/rxjs');
mix.copy('node_modules/systemjs', 'public/systemjs');
mix.copy('node_modules/es6-promise', 'public/es6-promise');
mix.copy('node_modules/es6-shim', 'public/es6-shim');
```

The structure needs to be changed to match your configuration. This is a quick fix. If I have time I'll find another solution for you.

If you need to test Angular 2, Laravel 5.2.  I think with those modifications you're ready to go.

I also committed changes to your GitHub.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Np @mrakodol. Happy that I helped!

Answer (score -2):

try to open firefox manually as root 
go to its directory (eventully in your personal repository) and run it .firefox , this error will diseppear , and appearly its related to the user privileges relatively to node_modules , the problem isn't clear , but like that u may run normally your app